# event.target null in React event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

Given the following code:

```
var
  React = require("react")
;

class ControlText extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }

  update() {
    console.log(event);
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    var value = this.state.value;
    return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.update.bind(this)} />
  }
}

module.exports = ControlText;
```

Every time I log the event object in update(), it returns an object with `target: null`, and `this.state.value` updates from `""` to `undefined`. This code diverges very little from the example on the [Forms docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), why can't I seem to get an event target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `event`(*you can name it as you want not only `event`*) argument to `update` method

```
update(event) {
       ^^^^^
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/30088/)

Comment: Yep, oh my god what a stupid oversight. Will approve this answer in 9 mins.